# How to use le and la

Tags: articles

If I wanted to say “I told her”, does it make sense to say j’ai la dit. I know when you translate it it usually says je lui ai dit.

Comment: So how does a person know if I’m talking about her or him if lui can be used for both?

Comment: That should have been a comment to my reply, not to your question. Anyway, how do a person know if my cousin is a boy or a girl if I say "I told it to my cousin ?" (In French: *Je l'ai dit à mon cousin / je l'ai dit à ma cousine*) There are cases where a language is more precise, and others where it's less. You can always say: *Je lui ai dit à elle (, pas a lui)* if that's a critical piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use that syntax.

1. You can't put a pronoun in the middle of a conjugated verb, only adverbs like *pas* (*Je ne lui ai **pas** dit*). The pronoun needs to be before the verb.
2. *La* is a direct object pronoun, but *her* (elle) is an indirect object of *dire* (j'ai dit **à** elle) so the right pronoun is ***lui***, regardless of the gender. *Lui* means both *to him* and *to her*.

> *je **lui** ai dit.*

Should you have used a direct object, *la* would have been the right pronoun:

> *La vérité, je **l**'ai dite.*

or even both a direct and indirect object:

> *Ma sœur, la vérité, je **la lui** ai dite.*